# Is AzureAD account needed for HoloLenses2

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

I have to setup the holo lenses but We didn't have the azure account right now. From What I searched, I believe I can't proceed with the setup because there is no azure account, right?. I am just asking it to be sure. Also, It will be perfect If you can share info about unity side. I know I will need MRTK but what else?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to have an Azure account on HoloLens, you can choose `I own it` in the `Who owns this HoloLens` step to enable you to sign in with a Microsoft account. For more information about how to set up your HoloLens2 please refer to this link:[Set up your HoloLens 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens2-start)

> It will be perfect If you can share info about unity side.

If you're new to MRTK or Mixed Reality development in Unity, we recommend you start at the beginning of our [Unity development journey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/unity-development-overview?tabs=arr%2CD365%2Chl2) in the Microsoft Docs.

In addition to this documentation available on learn.microsoft.com, Unity provided a manual to help you learn how to use Unity, from basic to advanced techniques, it is accessible online: [Unity User Manual 2020.3 (LTS)](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html)